# is this good approach to fetch data every n second by hitting server or rest API in android

Tags: java, android, api, rest

I am developing an application in which I want to fetch data after every 30 seconds so i am using this line of code:

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!Constants.IsCafeNewOrderAlert){
                    new_order_api();
                }
                reset_api();
            }
        },30000);
```

it works fine in my scenario but I just want to know is this approach is good or it can be done with some better code or approach.

thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not very scalable....

Comment: If you just want to sync your app with latest data then you can send triggers from your back-end server and in app when you get that trigger update the data via api call. This way your app will be synced with latest data and you don't need to call api in every 30 second. (Calling apis from mobile in every 30 second will effect your app performance as mobile resources are limited.)

Comment: yes that's why i am concern about calling api every 30 seconds. @AbhishekIppakayal what should i implement web sockets or by using FCM for this scenario?

Comment: I would suggest to use socket connection. Also search on web which is best for your scenario, you will get better clearity

Comment: thank you @AbhishekIppakayal for your suggestion.

Comment: On Android, FCM is probably the easiest way to do it, as websockets have limitations that FCM works around (specifically battery optimizations).  Especially if you have anything high priority that should be processed regardless of if the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

From battery point of view this approach is **very expensive (draining your battery)** because the radio has no chance to shut off to save energy.

Comment: yes you are right. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorkRequest to executes periodically an action such download content for your app: [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#schedule_periodic_work)

Answer (score -2):

there are some ways that are shorter, however they are a little harder to implement. I don't think it even matters if it is one line longer than something else unless it's some challenge.

```js
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!Constants.IsCafeNewOrderAlert){
                    new_order_api();
                }
                reset_api();
            }
        },30000);
```

What you have is perfectly fine and the easiest and one of the shortest ways to implement. Good luck with your app! And your welcome! If you find this helpful, please accept my answer as I need some reputation.

Comment: There's reasons (battery life among them) that you should not do this with networking calls.  Sending a network call every 30 seconds at all is a bad idea.